# how to add facebook login in phonegap using android studio

Tags: facebook, cordova

[image]i am just begginer in phonegap

**i have to integrate facebook login in my phonegap app which fetches all the information of user and and his friends**

after a hours of search on google i am unable to find  a proper documented example
  i meet with lots of plugin and example but unable to understand or getting error when executing so, can any one provide me the link or  explain me for this

i am using android studio

i have installed ant, node.js , phonegap, android studio java.
 for creating new phonegap project
 i have done following steps
 **open node.js and type following commands 
 1. phonegap create example
 2. cd example 
 3. phonegap build android
 this creates a project folder example in my c drive with some folders named "hooks","paltform","plugins","www" and config.xml   with package name"com.phonegap.example"**

then i try to install facebook plugin by typing this cordova plugin add https //github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="12344" --variable APP_NAME="xyz"

after this my system goes for a long batch process and comes with some error  after 30-40 minutes i  have attached a image of error

in facebook developer i have done following steps to make a new app registered app
1. add new app
2. then select platform android
3. skip and craete app id
4. enter captcha
5. add a display name

```
 ![error on command line][2]i didn't understand where i am doing wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found my mistake

it was in command line --

**"cordova plugin add https //github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="12344" --variable APP_NAME="xyz" "**

**so i rectified it and change it to

cd myprojectfolder
and then

cordova  plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myFacebookApplication"**

it solves my problem
this tutorial help me a lot http://www.phonegaptutorial.com/integrate-facebook-into-your-phonegap-app/